# GoogleCode Store Locator

Tags: json, google-maps, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, google-code

I am trying to build a search feature for my website. I have some address of dealers (lat,lng,descr fields) and upon searching for a location. I want to show on map, all dealers close around 10-15 miles range. 
I found this googlecode storelocator. 
However, after looking for weeks I could not find a single example of fetching data from mysql tables. 
http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/reference.html#storeLocator.DataFeed

I am trying to implement this in laravel 5 using eloquent and views. Any guidance or example would be wonderful.

I am a newbie so a detailed answer would be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your connections are set up in `config/database.php` and you can follow the ORM page on the Laravel 5 site to get going: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

After that, start a new question for specific help. But this is a pretty broad question as it stands.